# Align images horizontally with html

Tags: html, css

I created an html page and css and I integrated images in which I would like to align the images horizontally until the page horizontally and then wrap to fill the page with images.
I tried with this code:

```
<section class="main clearfix" style="display:inline;">
  <div class="work">
    <a href="inner.html">
      <img src="img/work1.jpg" class="">

    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="work">
    <a href="inner.html">
      <img src="img/work1.jpg" class="" alt="">

    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="work">
    <a href="inner.html">
      <img src="img/work3.jpg" class="" alt="">

    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="work">
    <a href="inner.html">
      <img src="img/work5.jpg" class="media" alt="">

    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="work">
    <a href="inner.html">
      <img src="img/work5.jpg" class="" alt="">

    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="work">
    <a href="inner.html">
      <img src="img/work6.jpg" class="" alt="">

    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="work">
    <a href="inner.html">
      <img src="img/work2.jpg" class="">

    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="work">
    <a href="inner.html">
      <img src="img/work3.jpg" class="">

    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="work">
    <a href="inner.html">
      <img src="img/work1.jpg" class="">

    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="work">
    <a href="inner.html">
      <img src="img/work1.jpg" class="">

    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="work">
    <a href="inner.html">
      <img src="img/work1.jpg" class="">

    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="work">
    <a href="inner.html">
      <img src="img/work1.jpg" class="">

    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="work">
    <a href="inner.html">
      <img src="img/work1.jpg" class="">

    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="work">
    <a href="inner.html">
      <img src="img/work1.jpg" class="">

    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="work">
    <a href="inner.html">
      <img src="img/work1.jpg" class="">

    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="work">
    <a href="inner.html">
      <img src="img/work1.jpg" class="">

    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="work">
    <a href="inner.html">
      <img src="img/work1.jpg" class="">

    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="work">
    <a href="inner.html">
      <img src="img/work1.jpg" class="">

    </a>
  </div>

</section>
```

file css :

```
.work {
  display: inline;
  float: auto;
}
.work img {
  width: 10%;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: -2px
}
```

it shows me the pictures like this: 
[image]

My problem is that this makes me a blank space to the right then back to the line.

Answer (score 2):

just use a flexbox

```
.main{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: i would like to display images like this :

Comment: and ? just add flex-grow: 1 to .work if you want items to fill all line.

Answer (score 0):

Beside of Martin's solution,

If you are concerned about size ration of the images, `flex` could be the best solution, or,

Use `object-fit: cover` on `img`, but **it is not supported by IE.**

Use `background-size: cover;` for background images, but, **horrible solution for SEO.**

Use `table display` and apply `overflow: hidden;` at the `.work` div, but, **horrible for responsiveness.**

You might want check responsive image topics, that would help you understand how images affect your website performance, extensions, sizes, between any other image characteristic that you need to be aware developing a good product.

Considering the display of the images, `flex` would be the best solution in such case.